# SUM and multiplying on calculated fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a piece of script which is pulling through the desired figures fine. Now I need to multiply the figure given by another calculated field (I shall call field x, which is a case statement with 9 'When Statements') then multiply that by 0.74.

I can not get this to work at all... any ideas... script below

```
Case 
    when Left([dbo].[Table1].FIELD 1,3) = 'NEW' and [Field 2] = 'Live'
Then 
    (SELECT distinct[dbo].[Table2].[Field a]
    FROM [MY_DATABASE].[dbo].[Table2]

right Join [dbo].[Table 3]
    on ([dbo].[Table2].[Field b]=[dbo].[Table 3].[Field 1])

Where [dbo].[Table2].[Field c] = 
    (Select 
        [dbo].[Table 3].[Field1]
            From [dbo].[Table 3]
                Where [dbo].[Table 3].[Field4] = @parameter
                    and [Field5] = '7')
                        and [dbo].[Table2].[Field D]= @Parameter
                            and [dbo].[Table2].[Field E]= '07')
  ELSE 0
  END 

  As [Named Field]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a good start.

Comment: _Column_, not field.

Answer (score 2):

One option here would be common table expressions.

I'd suggest wrapping your select in a cte, the selecting from it and performing any further calculations at the bottom level.

```
;with cte as ( 
    your original select query
)
    select * 
    ,      [named field] * [field x] as [calculated answer]
    from   cte
```

This saves you having to make the calculations over and over again.  There are performance concerns around cte's but they can help in these situations.  I'd test on your data and see how much of a hit you take.